# Android AppWidget onUpdate doesn't always update widgets

Tags: android, android-widget

I'm in the process of implementing a widget for a task list application. It doesn't really make sense to update the widget on an interval so I'm trying to update the widget whenever the user adds or deletes a task as such:

```
private void updateWidget() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(mContext, WidgetProvider.class);
    intent.setAction(AppWidgetManager.ACTION_APPWIDGET_UPDATE);
    int ids[] = AppWidgetManager.getInstance(mContext).getAppWidgetIds(
            new ComponentName(mContext, WidgetProvider.class));
    intent.putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_IDS, ids);
    mContext.sendBroadcast(intent);
}
```

Here is the onUpdate method of the WidgetProvider class (the only overridden method):

```
@Override
public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int[] appWidgetIds) {
    if (appWidgetIds != null) {
        for (int i = 0; i < appWidgetIds.length; i++) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(context, WidgetService.class);
            intent.putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID, appWidgetIds[i]);
            intent.setData(Uri.parse(intent.toUri(Intent.URI_INTENT_SCHEME)));
            RemoteViews widget = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.widget_layout);

            widget.setRemoteAdapter(appWidgetIds[i], R.id.widget_listview, intent);

            appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetIds[i], widget);
        }
    }
    super.onUpdate(context, appWidgetManager, appWidgetIds);
}
```

The onGetViewFactory method of the WidgetService class:

```
@Override
public RemoteViewsFactory onGetViewFactory(Intent intent) {
    return new TaskViewsFactory(getBaseContext());
}
```

And the relavant part of the Manifest:

```
<receiver
        android:name="com.nick.android.todo.widget.WidgetProvider"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_UPDATE" />
        </intent-filter>

        <meta-data
            android:name="android.appwidget.provider"
            android:resource="@xml/widget_provider" />
    </receiver>

    <service
        android:name="com.nick.android.todo.widget.WidgetService"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:permission="android.permission.BIND_REMOTEVIEWS" />
```

If I remove and add the widget to the home screen the list gets populated correctly. Adding tasks sometimes randomly works but I cannot figure out why/why not.

**Edit**: It seems that my WidgetService.onGetViewFactory() isn't always called. (The widgets get updated when it is)

Comment: is onUpdate() called when you sent Brooadcast every time?

Comment: @GopalRao  Yes it is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I finally figured it out.

The widget was indeed updating but with the same items. I needed to override onDataSetChanged() to get a fresh list of items and call notifyAppWidgetViewDataChanged:

```
appWidgetManager.notifyAppWidgetViewDataChanged(appWidgetIds, R.id.widget_listview);
```